# [UWP][C++] How to change location of App.xaml

Tags: c++, xaml, uwp

I'm leaning programming on UWP using C++.

I created sample by using New Project -> Visual C++ -> Windows -> Universal -> Blank App (Universal windows). This sample can be compiled without error and run correctly.

The problem is, I want to move all source files (xaml, cpp, h) into a subfolder named "src" for managing.

It will look like this:

root project directory

| -- Assets

| -- src

|         | -- App.xaml

|         | -- App.xaml.cpp

|         | -- App.xaml.h

|         | -- (the rest files: mainpage, subpage, etc.)

| -- Sample.sln

| -- Sample.vcxproj

| -- Package.appxmanifest

But after moving those files and changing all paths related to them in vcxproj , I couldn't compile the project.

The error I got is " XamlCompiler error WMC1008: Application main file must be named App.xaml".

This is new ApplicationDefinition field in the vcxproj file

```
 <ApplicationDefinition Include="src\App.xaml">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>      
    </ApplicationDefinition>
    <Page Include="src\MainPage.xaml">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </Page>
```

I'm pretty sure that we can change the location of App.xaml because the offical samples on https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples can do it, but they put them in a parent folder. I inspected those samples but still couldn't find out how to do that.

Could you please help me :)

Answer (score 0):

Due to the restriction of Windows Store Applications, you could not move the "App.xaml" relevant files to other sub folders.

What you see in the UWP official samples. The samples actually use the `<Link>` element to virtually move files around. When you open a project, you will find that the "App.xaml" file will still be copied into the root directory.